# Opengl boolean subtraction

Tags: opengl, operators, shapes

Is it possible to do Boolean operations between polygons?

I want to do a figure like this in OpenGL and I thinking of doing it with a sphere and four subtractions with four smaller spheres.

[image]

Comment: Spheres are not polygons. Do you mean boolean operations on solids? In any case OpenGL does neither on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible with just OpenGL.
OpenGL is a very low level API. it allows you to display polygons and that's about it.

What you're describing is usually done in the application level above OpenGL.
Look at the bottom of this article for some references on libraries that does that:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't think that is so difficult. I'm working with 2D polygons or shapes. I will learn haw to draw different kind of curves.

Comment: Well, actually on the fragment level you can use the stencil buffer to do boolen operations. But those are then not on the polygons, but the rasterized fragments.